# How to render the audio from a synth to a buffer (array of PCM values) with the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I have a simple synth that plays a note for some length of time:

```
// Creating audio graph
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
oscillator.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

// Setting parameters
oscillator.type = "sine";
oscillator.frequency.value = 2500;

// Run audio graph
var currentTime = offlineCtx.currentTime;
oscillator.start(currentTime);
oscillator.stop(currentTime + 1);
```

How can I get the PCM data of the sound the synthesiser makes? I've managed to do this with audio samples by using [decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData), but I can't find an equivalent for an audio graph that isn't based on loading a sample.

I specifically want to render the audio graph with the [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext) since I only care about retrieving the PCM data as fast as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Try my item here, will let you record a certain number of seconds into a group of frames which you can process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728518/how-to-export-last-3s-data-of-a-web-audio-stream/38638448#38638448

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to use an offline context and then you don't actually use an offline context.  So you should do

```
var offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(nc, length, rate)
```

where `nc` = number of channels, `length` is the number of samples, and `rate` is the sample rate you want to use.

Create your graph, start everything and then do

```
offlineCtx.startRendering().then(function (buffer) {
  // buffer has the PCM data you want. Save it somewhere, 
  // or whatever
})
```

(I'm not sure all browsers support promises from an offline context.  If not, use offlineCtx.oncomplete to get the data.  See the spec.)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found an answer here: http://www.pp4s.co.uk/main/tu-sms-audio-recording.html#co-tu-sms-audio-recording__js but you will not like it. Apparently, the Audio API is not yes standardized enough for this to work on all browsers. So I have been able to run the code above in Firefox, but not Chrome.

Basic ideas:

- use *dest = ac.[createMediaStreamDestination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)();* to get a destination 
  of the sound
- use *new [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)(dest.stream);* to get a recorder
- use the MediaRecorder [ondataavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) and [stop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/onstop) events to get the data and combine it into a [Blob](http://www.javascripture.com/Blob)